# On Linux Firefox is listening on several UDP ports on 0.0.0.0

Tags: linux, networking, firefox

On Linux, Firefox is listening on UDP port, usually on ports 30000 and higher. What is the reason for this and why not just localhost, but 0.0.0.0, i.e. the interface exposed to the network as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UDP is not connection-based, so both ends have to be listening for two-way communication. Thus if Firefox wants to receive any responses from UDP services it is talking to, it needs to have open ports bound to a routable interface.

Since Firefox 88, [HTTP/3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3) has been enabled by default, using UDP for web browsing with servers that support it. DNS lookups may involve remote UDP requests from Firefox (but not usually on Linux systems). Many P2P systems like WebRTC also use UDP.

Comment: and this can be tested by running `ss -aunp | grep -i firefox` while browsing this URL: https://http3check.net/ . The browser has to enable HTTP/3.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed HTTP/3! Switching it off and restarting now shows no open listening ports.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan Note that whether or not you consider Firefox to have "open listening ports" is just a matter of semantics. With ordinary TCP connections, Firefox still has to listen for replies on the source port, but this does not appear in netstat/ss as it is implicit in the connection-based nature of the protocol. HTTP/3 basically performs a similar bidirectional packet conversation, but the listening source port happens to show up in netstat/ss because that's the convention for UDP (it would be hard to hide it).

Comment: Note that technically, HTTP/3 does not use UDP, it uses QUIC. QUIC is a Layer 3 protocol just like UDP or TCP. Rightfully, it *should* be implemented as an L3 protocol on top of IP, but for reasons of backwards-compatibility with existing firewalls, home routers, NAT boxes, and other middle boxes, it was decided to implement QUIC on top of UDP. So, it is a Layer protocol implemented on top of another Layer 3 protocol, so to speak. But the open UDP ports are really a technicality, functionally, HTTP/3 uses QUIC, not UDP.

Comment: @TooTea With TCP I get that it has to listen to replies, but this is not an "open for all" listening, but just traffic on an already open TCP connection.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan That's the same thing. Anyone can spoof a "reply" packet with the right addresses and ports for an existing TCP connection, just like they can send a "reply" UDP packet to a "listening" port. It is up to the receiver to discard any such spoofed packets, and that's one of the main tasks done by the TCP or QUIC stack, respectively. Unless there are critical security bugs in those stacks, it should be quite hard to successfully get a spoofed reply all the way to the application layer. Whether or not you see a "listening" port in ss has very little effect on that.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan FWIW, QUIC replies are much harder to spoof than TCP replies. The former cryptographically authenticates all packets, so it should be nearly impossible to forge a reply. The latter relies purely on the addresses&ports plus a 32-bit sequence number to validate if a reply should be accepted as part of a connection. So in the absence of TLS, it is quite easy for a man-in-the-middle to inject a reply into an HTTP connection. So on average, seeing a listening UDP port is a sign of _better_ security than running over TCP.

Comment: @TooTea Regarding TCP listening to new connections vs receiving packets for an already established connection: isn't it at least somewhat easier to abuse a the listening port, as it just sits there open, on a static port number, while the established connection ports open and close as connections come and go, and also the port numbers themselves change between these? --- Anyway, what triggered this question was that I was doing a layman's security audit on my machine and was confused by the open ports by Firefox, and have now gotten yet a bit more knowledgeable on the topic. :)

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan But the listening UDP ports you saw aren't static, they're also ephemeral. If you `watch 'ss -ulp | grep firefox'`, you'll see ports come and go as connections are established and torn down (ports will stay around for a short while after the connection is finished, just like TCP keeps listening for replies for a while in one of the *-WAIT states after a connection gets closed). There's really very little practical difference between ephemeral TCP source ports and the same for QUIC. That the latter show up in `ss -l` unlike the former is basically an implementation detail.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan If you're curious, you can open `about:networking` in Firefox, go to the Sockets tab, and you should be able to correlate UDP entries in there with what you see in `ss -ulp | grep firefox`. It's not easy to match them 1:1 as Firefox does not show the local port numbers, but at least the number of entries should match.

Comment: @JörgWMittag In other words, HTTP/3 uses UDP because it uses QUIC, which is implemented on top of UDP.

Comment: @user3840170 If we get really nit-picky about this, then I think we do use UDP for HTTP/3. What I don't understand though is, that wikipedia lists both UDP and QUIC as transport layer protocols. But if QUIC is using UDP, shouldn't it be a layer higher?

Comment: The layers are more conceptual than technical. We call QUIC a transport-layer protocol because it performs the functions of a transport-layer protocol; just because it is encapsulated in another transport-layer protocol does not necessarily make it a higher layer.